# How to use multiple auxiliary xaml files with MainWindow.xaml in WinUI3

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I'm working on an app containing multiple components which are laid out over the main window according to layout specs.  I would like to use multiple auxiliary xaml files to help minimize the code in my main code files and to organize my xaml/cs files according to the view model they support.  I would like to have one MainWindow.xaml file containing minimal markup which binds to Grid/StackPanel component markup located in multiple auxiliary xaml files.

I've tried the following:

BlankPage.xaml
Xaml:
<Page x:Class="namespace.MainWindow" .../>
CSharp:
public partial class BlankPage : Page {}

BlankPage.xaml
Xaml:
<Page x:Class="namespace.Models.BlankPage" .../>
CSharp:
public partial class MainWindow {}

Comment: Seems like you're looking for what's called "Custom Controls" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/xaml-templated-controls-csharp-winui-3

Comment: Simon, thanks for you input, although the article you suggested was mostly to do with dependency objects.  As I mentioned in my post above, I would like to know if there is a way to associate multiple auxiliary xaml files to the main xaml file to enable binding between the two; I would like to pass content from multiple auxiliary markup files to the main markup file.  Any ideas?

Comment: There's no concept of "auxiliary markup file with binding" because it's completely filled with the custom control concept, it's just a .xaml file + a .cs file wich may contain nothing special

Comment: Is that to say that there is no way to import the content of a 'Page' file into a 'Frame' element in the main xaml file, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct, you need [XamlReader.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader.load?view=winrt-22621), which *Parses a well-formed XAML fragment and creates a corresponding object tree, and returns the root of the object tree*. And then you can manipulate the object tree, for example `stackPanelRoot.Children.Add(TheRootObjectOfTheCreatedObjectTree.)`.

Also see [Show multiple views with AppWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/app-window) and https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/3611 for more information.